# Creating URIs for webmethods

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service and I want my client to use servicemethods directly using a URL without creating a proxy class and object for it. How to generate the direct URLs for each webmethod. IF I have 5 webmethods, I want 5 URLS to give to clients to consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your web service methods without generating the proxy class and object then you should make that service as REST service.

Please look at the below links that will provide you basic idea of what WCF REST Services is.

[Beginner Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)

[step by step REST service](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/Simple-Steps-For-RESTful-Service.html)

[MSDN API for REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will look into those links.

Comment: Hi Jenish, Provided links were really useful. Thanks a lot!